# convert date in php day/month name, year

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query that inserts date in this format

```
$time = date("m-d-y");
```

But when I Fetch and output date it shows wrong date. real: October 2020 but outputs: January 1970

```
$time = $row1['time'];
$newDate = date('F Y', strtotime($time));
echo $newDate;
```

How do I output date in this format: 20 OCT, 2020

Comment: What about in your MySQL table? how does the data being stored? What is the datatype for the `date` column in MySQL table?

Comment: It would be better to store `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` for display purposes, format the value on the client side.

Comment: Your code seems fine, just the problem seems with your `$time`

Comment: data is being stored in this format: 10-29-20, table type is VARCHAR

Comment: Why though? If you can change that, you should. Using the proper format and column type would make everything using this value much simpler.

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the datatype for the date column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to store date/time using varchar datatype. If you can change it, please do. However, if you can't change database structure, you can use `date_create_from_format()` to create a DateTime object from a custom format:

```
echo date_create_from_format('m-d-y', "10-29-20")->format('F Y');
```

Output:

```
October 2020
```

**Edit**: Change the format part to `->format('d M, Y')` to match your desired format
Output:

```
29 Oct, 2020
```

Comment: It works But I was looking for something like "20 OCT, 2020"